# error Cannot read property 'files' of undefined when press button upload file

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7, angular-components

I work on angular 7 project

I face issue when select file then press button upload to get selected file

then it show error Cannot read property 'files' of undefined

as below

```
DeliverySystemComponent.html:25 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined
```

and that actually my issue

so How to solve this issue

what I try is

delivery html component

```
<app-custom-upload #cusUpload nbTooltip="upload excel file" nbTooltipPlacement="bottom"
      nbTooltipStatus="primary" (complete)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)"></app-custom-upload>

<button (click)="uploadFile(files)" class="btn btn-link" style="margin-right: 0px">
          <i nbTooltip="Import Template" nbTooltipPlacement="bottom" nbTooltipStatus="primary">
            <nb-icon icon="cloud-upload-outline"></nb-icon>
          </i>
        </button>
```

delivery component type script

```
fileToUpload: File = null;
handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
  if (files.length == 0) {
      return;
    }  
 
  this.fileToUpload = files.item(0);
 
} 
public uploadFile = (files) => {
   
  const formData = new FormData();
  
  formData.append('file', this.fileToUpload,this.fileToUpload.name);
 }
```

[image: upload file error]

when using

```
<input type="file"  
             id="file"  
             (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
```

instead of

```
  <app-custom-upload #cusUpload nbTooltip="upload excel file" nbTooltipPlacement="bottom"
          nbTooltipStatus="primary" (complete)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)"></app-custom-upload>
```

it working so what is issue and how to solve it

Comment: can any one help me if any thing not clear i can explain

Comment: Based on the code and HTML you show, the only place it could be is `(complete)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)"` in the HTML and `$event.target` is undefined (the key in the error is that there is an attempt to get a `.files` from something that is `undefined`, so look for `.files` to where it is happening).

Comment: thank you for reply so what i do to solve issue

Comment: when use that <input type="file"  
             id="file"  
             (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">  alternative of using <app-custom-upload #cusUpload nbTooltip="upload excel file" nbTooltipPlacement="bottom"
      nbTooltipStatus="primary" (complete)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)"></app-custom-upload> it working when use first statement so what i do and why this issue happen and how to solve

Comment: see updated post

Comment: so what i do to solve issue

Comment: Add some debugging code to check what `$event` is when the handler is triggered? You may have some issue with Angular syntax or it could be something else.

Comment: how to debug event

Comment: Have you tried passing `$event` to `handleFileInput`? You could then examine it in a breakpoint instead of it crashing when trying to access `undefined.files` when you try and pass that in.